# SonarQube 6.0 authorization using groups

Tags: sonarqube, authorization, sonarqube-web

I am using SonarQube (SQ) 6.0 community version and trying to setup authorization using groups and project permissions. There doesn't appear to be a way to assign permissions to a created group, even though the defined SQ groups have permissions assigned to them. What I wanted to do was assign permissions to a created group via the Admininistration->Security->Global Permissions process. But this action only returns the Anyone and sonar-administrators defined groups based on the usage of the internal API api/permissions/groups, which only returns groups with permissions. This same API is used in the action Administration->Projects->Management->Actions->Edit Permissions. From this last action the goal was to remove permissions for this project from the Anyone group and allow permissions from a created group (which would apply to the users in that group). But that doesn't seem possible. I've looked at permission templates, but that doesn't seem to allow association to a group. What I'm really attempting to do is a common RBAC process, which SQ does not seem to support. Is there a solution in SQ for this capability?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you using the UI or web services?

Comment: I am using the UI, but had logging configured to debug to determine what APIs were being used by the UI. At a high level the goal is allow access to a project for only users defined in a certain created group. So viewing source code and performing other actions on a project would only be allowed to users in that group (some access would also be allowed to users in the sonar-administrators group).

Answer (score 3):

Yup, the UI is very confusing in this area, I struggled for quite some time before realising what to do.

What you need to do is first search for a string in the search box ("sonar" is a good query), and then the list will be populated with all users/groups matching that query. You can then assign them permissions as you see fit.

Answer (score -1):

There are two different concepts at work here. Global permissions grant users and groups the ability to make global-level changes, i.e. changes that effect *everyone* such as which plugins are installed and what rules are active in a Quality Profile. Project permissions grant users and groups the ability to see and change individual projects.

Once your group is created and populated, you have two options:

## Edit Permissions of Individual Permissions

Give the group specific permissions to individual projects by navigating to the project, then *Administration > Permissions*. This could get tedious if you have a lot of projects to update.

## Create a Permissions Template

Create a [permission template](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-PermissionTemplatesforDefaultProjectPermissions) (*Administration > Security > Permission Templates*) and populate it by granting the group specific permissions. **At this point no permissions have actually changed**.

Once your template is properly constructed, you can apply it to projects individually, en masse, and/or by default as new projects are created via the template's Project Key Pattern. You can also make your new template the default so that its settings are automatically applied to all new projects regardless of project key.

**Note** that there is no ongoing relationship between a Permissions Template and the projects to which it has been applied. Subsequently editing a template *will not* update the permissions of any project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The two UI options that you have listed are the options I have tried to perform. The problem is that my created group is not listed when I perform those options, so I am unable to assign group permissions. When I determined the API that is used to list the groups for those 2 UI options (using the DEBUG logging option), the API documentation indicated that only groups with assigned permissions are listed (that is the API I had listed earlier). So the real issue is since my created group is not being listed by those 2 UI options, there is no way to assign group permissions.

Comment: Diagnosing this will likely take more interaction than is 'allowed' in comments. Try opening a [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube) thread.